# conversions from google don't match up with the number of leads i got that had gclid set

Tags: google-ads

On Friday, August 11, I got 152 leads, according to Google Ads. And yet, according to my local database, I got 111 leads that had a gclid. I'm trying to understand why.

A number of possibilities occur to me:

1. I suppose it's possible there was a glitch in my website that was preventing leads from being saved but I'm not seeing any evidence of that
2. Maybe Google Ads is using a different timezone then I'm using when I query my database (I'm using CDT, GMT-5)?
3. Maybe leads can come through without a gclid?

Any ideas?